# How to kill list of jobs using dynamic job name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i stored list of jobs in temp table and that need to be killed.

```
use msdb
declare @counts int, @jobname nvarchar(1000), @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @counts = (select count(*) from #jobslist)
while @counts>=1
begin
set @jobname = (select name from #jobslist where rnk=@counts)

set @cmd = 'use msdb EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'+''''+@jobname+''''
--select @jobname
print @cmd
exec @cmd
set @counts=@counts-1
end
```

and getting this error

> use msdb EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'JOBA'
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 30

> Could not find stored procedure 'use msdb EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'JobA''.

Comment: EXEC(@cmd) should do the trick

Comment: exec @cmd means execute procedure with name in the variable

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
use msdb
declare @counts int, @jobname nvarchar(1000), @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @counts = (select count(*) from #jobslist)
while @counts>=1
begin
set @jobname = (select name from #jobslist where rnk=@counts)

set @cmd = 'EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'+''''+@jobname+''''
--select @jobname
print @cmd
exec @cmd
set @counts=@counts-1
end
```

---

```
DECLARE @counts INT, @jobname NVARCHAR(1000), @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Switch to the msdb database
USE msdb;

SET @cmd = 'EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N''test''';

-- Execute the command
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
```

---

```
USE msdb;
DECLARE @counts INT, @jobname NVARCHAR(1000), @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @jobname = 'test';

SET @cmd = N'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @job_name';
    
EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, N'@job_name NVARCHAR(1000)', @job_name = @jobname;
```

Comment: did not work
Error: -
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job N'JobA'
Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 30
Database 'EXEC msdb' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: same error 
**Could not find stored procedure 'EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'JobA'**

Comment: Could you just run - `EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job N'JobA` to confirm you have access to execute it.

Comment: executed fin
**Job 'JobA' stopped successfully.**

Comment: Could you execute and the second part in order to confirm you can refer the routine via dynamic T-sQL?

Comment: working with this   **exec (@cmd) **

Comment: Could you try and the last one?